# How do I stringify macros that are the results of operations on macros?

Tags: c, string, macros, c-preprocessor

Here's a program that illustrates my problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NUMERATOR 8
#define DENOMINATOR 2
#define QUOTIENT (NUMERATOR / DENOMINATOR)

#define ZSTR(x) XSTR(#x)
#define YSTR(x) XSTR(x)
#define XSTR(x) STR(x)
#define STR(x) #x

int main()
{
    printf("QUOTIENT:       %d\n", QUOTIENT);
    printf("STR(QUOTIENT):  %s\n", STR(QUOTIENT));
    printf("XSTR(QUOTIENT): %s\n", XSTR(QUOTIENT));
    printf("YSTR(QUOTIENT): %s\n", YSTR(QUOTIENT));
    printf("ZSTR(QUOTIENT): %s\n", ZSTR(QUOTIENT));
    return 0;
}
```

And here's its output:

```
$ gcc -g -Wall -o stringify stringify.c && ./stringify 
QUOTIENT:       4
STR(QUOTIENT):  QUOTIENT
XSTR(QUOTIENT): (8 / 2)
YSTR(QUOTIENT): (8 / 2)
ZSTR(QUOTIENT): "QUOTIENT"
```

I would like to have a the string literal `"4"` passed to the compiler, but I'm losing hope.
This is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653214/stringification-of-a-macro-value), but adds a level.

Comment: I don't think you can do that... the `#` operator works on a preprocessor token not an expression so I'd not be at all surprised if there is no way to do this whatsoever.

Comment: @Spudd86: Yeah, I was just hoping there was a way to do math in the preprocessor and that someone here would know about it.

Comment: you CAN do math in the preprocessor, you just can't stringize the result `#if 0 == 1 - 1` will result in true

Comment: @Spudd86: Okay, so I was hoping there was a way for me to use the result of math done in the preprocessor. Maybe I should `#if QUOTIENT != 4 #error`.

Comment: Related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275004/how-to-stringify-an-expression-in-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With some tricks you can implement basic arithmetic in a C99 conforming preprocessor. [P99](http://p99.gforge.inria.fr) implements arithmetic and logic for *small* decimal numbers. E.g

```
P99_IF_GT(1,0)(true)(false)
P99_ADD(3, 7)
P99_MUL(7, 2)
P99_DIV(7, 2)
```

would be preprocessed to something like

```
1
10
14
3
```

These macros can be processed further, stringified and everthing you like.

```
P99_STRINGIFY(P99_PASTE2(XXX_, P99_ADD(3, 7)))
```

leads to `"XXX_10"` as the result of preprocessing.

Comment: You're making me feel bad about wanting the preprocessor to do this stuff for me. (Un?)fortunately, I can't use a C99 conforming preprocessor for this without rewriting all my build scripts.

Comment: Actually, you only need a C89 conformant preprocessor to do this kind of op-by-macro-paste stuff from P99.  Other P99 stuff requires C99

Comment: @Chris, this heavily uses `__VA_ARGS__`, no? This is a C99 feature. Many compilers implement this as an extension to C89, the P99 implementation uses all tricks of the prescribed evaluation order of parameters a such things, so they'd better implement that part of C99 completely.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance... Where is the body for `P99_ADD` and friends?

Comment: @jww, what exactly do you want to know? Where to find the source of P99?

Comment: What is the body. How do we make it happen? How do we add the numbers?

Comment: By body, you mean the definition? Did you see the link to the source?

Answer (score 4):

You can define macros that paste together their arguments and then define a (large) number of other macros that do the evaluation as kind of a table lookup:

```
#define DIV(X, Y)  DIV_(X, Y)
#define DIV_(X, Y) DIV_##X##_##Y
#define DIV_0_1  0
#define DIV_1_1  1
#define DIV_2_1  2
    :
#define DIV_8_2  4
    :
```

This is kind of tedious, but you can easily write a little program to generate a header file with the above stuff in it and run that as part of your build process.  Then you just need

```
#define QUOTIENT  DIV(NUMERATOR, DENOMINATOR)
```

Note that his kind of thing only works for unsigned integers -- if you need negative numbers or floating point, it won't work

Comment: I have a feeling this is a lot like what Jens suggested, but exposing the ugly a little more.

Answer (score 2):

The best you can do is [stringify](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html) the expansion of the macro which is done with your `XSTR` and `YSTR` examples. Although it may compile to `4` with optimizations all the **pre**processor will be able see is `(8 / 2)`

Answer (score 2):

Well, I'm a little reluctant to admit I know one way to make this work.

Attack it from the other direction. You want your compiler to see something like this.

```
#define QUOTIENT 4
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  printf("QUOTIENT:       %d\n", QUOTIENT);
  return 0;
}
```

How do we do that without using a literal "4" in the definition of QUOTIENT, since the macro processor won't help us? By using an additional preprocessor. Write a source file, stringify.c.awk, like this.

```
/* stringify.c.awk --  Source file for stringify.c  
   (Put build instructions here.)  
 */
#define QUOTIENT NUMERATOR/DENOMINATOR
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  printf("QUOTIENT:       %d\n", QUOTIENT);
  return 0;
}
```

Write the secondary preprocessor in awk. I deliberately used a really tight regular expression. I think it's the most likely regex to fail if there are changes to the source file, and I think that's usually what you want. (I usually want to discourage cosmetic changes to the #define.)

```
# stringify.awk -- calculate and substitute the value for #define QUOTIENT.
BEGIN {
  NUMERATOR = 8;
  DENOMINATOR = 2;
}
{
  if ($0~/^#define QUOTIENT NUMERATOR\/DENOMINATOR$/) {
    sub(/NUMERATOR\/DENOMINATOR/, NUMERATOR/DENOMINATOR);
  } 
  print $0;
}
```

Now you can build stringify.c from the stringify.c.awk file.

```
$ awk -f stringify.awk stringify.c.awk > stringify.c
$ gcc -Wall -o stringify stringify.c
$ ./stringify
QUOTIENT:       4
```

A makefile and generous comments takes a lot of the pain away.

(m4 won't help for more or less the same reasons the C preprocessor won't help.)

Comment: Wow, this is like a contest for things we shouldn't do while writing software. I'll fix it in documentation. +1 for reluctance.