# How to perform calculation in preprocessor with stringification in C

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, c-strings, stringification

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to stringify an expression in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275004/how-to-stringify-an-expression-in-c)

I hope I can find some solution of my issue here.

I want to add the hex numbers defined in ADD1 and need to put the same in `*str` in string form.

> This is only a example, to prove its possibility first. I am actually
>   doing the same in a header file.

```
#include <stdio.h>


#define XMK_STR(x)      #x
#define MK_STR(x)       XMK_STR(x)
#define ADD1 0x6000+0x10

main()
{
        char *str = "START " MK_STR(ADD1) "\n";
        printf(str);
}
```

Comment: So you want a "0x6010" string?

Comment: @ouah requirement is similar but i have to do the same in header file actually.

Comment: @linuxexplore it's not a calculation performed in the preprocessor but an optimization performed by the compiler. To read as: no that optimization will be performed by the compiler then AFTER the preprocessor has been executed (so you can't stringify that with a preprocessor macro).

Comment: That's is not good for me, i need to hardcode this types of values then :-(

Answer (score 4):

No. You can't perform calculations using preprocessor. It's essentially a text-replacer.

You can use `sprintf()` and print the added result into `str` for that you can use `ADD1`.

Comment: Yeah to make it explicit, sprintf will not be part of preprocessor. It will only execute when compiler runs which is after the preprocessor

Comment: So that's mean i can't do this in header file? i am looking for some hack if there is ;-)

Comment: yes, you can't do that. However, you can try something like http://ideone.com/CHQLA or http://ideone.com/1VNUs.

Comment: Thanks @KingsIndian, but i have only header file, there is no main().

Comment: I need to put the output of MK_STR(ADD1) in another #define line :-P